# IBM MobileFirst Platfform CLI 6.3: Unable to load MobileFirst server and admin Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

We have followed the silent installation procedure on remote server as mentioned in the IBM Developer documentation of 6.3 from the link:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/dev/t_silent_installation.html

Downloaded the MobileFirst CLI 6.3 file from the link::
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_cli_installer_6.3.0.zip

unzipped it to MobileFirst CLI 6.3.0 and copied installer.properties file with fallowing content in that,

> LICENSE_ACCEPTED=TRUE
>
> USER_INSTALL_DIR=/opt/ibm/Worklight-CLI

and staying in the same folder, i installed the CLI 3.0 to the specified folder:

```
./install_linux.bin -i silent -f installer.properties
```

App has installed to the /opt/ibm/Worklight-CLI directory.

We then created a sample app as per Command Line commands specified in the link:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/r_wl_cli_commands_and_their_definitions.html

```
$ mfp create MyProject
$ cd MyProject
$ mfp build
$ mfp deploy
```

After app build and deployment, when we tried to check the MobileFirst Console over browser, with link:
`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10080/worklightconsole`

after logging in to admin/admin credentials, page shows, loading the environments, but after waiting for 30 sec or more, it throws error as in the attached image.
But in log file shows some JAR file are missing. And i tried installing fresh copy of MFP 6.3 many times. but all time the same issue.

Please find the attached logs file and screenshot.

I am not able to find out what is the exact problem.

> Server error. Contact the server administrator.
>
> **Server Configuration:**
>
> - Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS
> - MobileFirst Version : 6.3.0.00.20141127-1401
> - java version:  "1.7.0_65"
> - java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
> - OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
> - OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

The Console error Message:
[image]

**Log file:**

> [12/11/14 10:27:57:376 IST] 0000002f
> m.ibm.ws.container.service.app.deploy.ManifestClassPathUtils W
> SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-api.jar can not be found in
> jar file
> wsjar:file:/home/administrator/.ibm/mobilefirst/6.3.0/server/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/apps/worklightconsole.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar
> or its parent.
>
> [12/11/14 10:27:57:376 IST] 0000002f
> m.ibm.ws.container.service.app.deploy.ManifestClassPathUtils W
> SRVE9967W: The manifest class path activation.jar can not be found in
> jar file
>
> wsjar:file:/home/administrator/.ibm/mobilefirst/6.3.0/server/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/apps/worklightconsole.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar
> or its parent.
>
> [12/11/14 10:27:57:376 IST] 0000002f
> m.ibm.ws.container.service.app.deploy.ManifestClassPathUtils W
> SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jsr173_1.0_api.jar can not be found
> in jar file
>
> wsjar:file:/home/administrator/.ibm/mobilefirst/6.3.0/server/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/apps/worklightconsole.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar
> or its parent.
>
> [12/11/14 10:27:57:377 IST] 0000002f
> m.ibm.ws.container.service.app.deploy.ManifestClassPathUtils W
> SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb1-impl.jar can not be found in
> jar file
>
> wsjar:file:/home/administrator/.ibm/mobilefirst/6.3.0/server/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/apps/worklightconsole.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar
> or its parent.
>
> [12/11/14 10:27:57:637 IST] 00000029
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I
> SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: IBMJMXConnectorREST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only linked to the documentation. Please edit the question and describe what you've actually *done*.

These are the steps I have taken (based on the [CLI tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/advanced-client-side-development/using-cli-create-build-manage-project-artifacts/#testServers)) in order to create a new project and application using MobileFirst CLI and then open MobileFirst Console:

System:

- OS X 10.10.1
- Oracle Java (default installed by the OS)

In Terminal:

1. cd /Users/idanadar/Desktop
2. mfp create testProject
3. cd testProject
4. mfp add hybrid testApp
5. mfp start
6. mfp build
7. mfp deploy
8. mfp console

The console was opened: 
[image]

Comment: I have edited the question and provided the steps that i followed to install the MFP CLI 6.3.0

Comment: Run "mfp stop" and then follow my steps and report back the results.

Comment: Hi I have stoped the server by: mfp stop and restarted it and did the same step again: [link] (https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0HJ-GQu4AmfT3VEX19vU2h6UFU/edit?usp=drivesdk)  But still facing same issue

Comment: Please find the server log files that have generated during this operation in this [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0HJ-GQu4Amfb19xdEZIaXI3cms/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can i know what are all the ports that Worklight will use apart from 10080.

Comment: For the server component in the development environment (or CLI), that's it: 10080. If there is Analytics platform involved as well (installed on a separate server anyway... - these can be found in the Knowledge Center by searching for "ports").

Comment: Thank You. I will check the Knowledge Center for ports.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if there are any spaces in the path for your eclipse workspace. There is a known limitation with Liberty 8.5.5.3, which is the internal development server included in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3, that you cannot have whitespace in the path name:

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_known_limitations.html

The failures, which match what shows in your log file, can occur on console startup and app deploy or preview.

Comment: The Log file message is loaded when MFP server starts. And everything is normal until and unless when we open worklight console to check the deployed apps. just for test, i have installed and checked the same on local Ubuntu system, thanks, its worked. But not on remote linux server.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is with the Hosted Server. They have opened the port 10080 partially. as port is allowing one way communication. because of some security reason, Hosting Server organisation has put some restriction over it. Now its resolved. Now we can able to deploy, and check the deployed apps over the worklight Console.

Thank you all for your suggestions and effort to go through my long listed question and trying out to resolve it.

I posted this comment: as some other persons may face same issue. so at least they can rid of this kind of issue ASAP.